# Chrome disables extension — how to understand why?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that makes ajax requests in the background. It can work for a few hours and then Chrome will disable it. This extension is in dev mode.

Is there any way to log why Chrome does that? I'm on Windows.

Comment: My gut feeling is it could be crashing, or running out of memory, or be stuck in an infinite loop, so Chrome kills it- that appears as 'Disabled'. I've seen that happen before. Check your code and look at the Chrome task manager /dev tools for your extension.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome errs on the side of caution whenever it's dealing with dev mode apps. It assumes that if you're a real dev you can re-enable it, and if you're not then it just saved you from being hacked. It will offer to disable file based apps on every restart and automatically disable packaged local apps.

There is nothing you can do from inside an app to view or change disabled state.

Your best bet is to [publish it on the Chrome app store](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish) - this will cost you $5 the first time you do it, but includes an update service.

Comment: this does not explain why it will disable by itself during the same chrome session after being enabled.

Comment: It was working fine last week, and now it disables the app after an hour or so.